# Using an If Statement to change the text in a shape using cell values

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, language

I am trying to create a buttons in excel that have different text depending on the language selected in a combobox.

So far, I have linked the combobox value to a cell (a choice between Japanese/English being stored in that cell (C11)).

When I tried to use the following if statement in a shape to change the button text dependent on language, I get an error.

```
=IF(C11=B11,B107,C107)
```

- C11 is the linked cell for the combobox value
- B11 is the value English
- B107 is the English Text
- C107 is the Japanese Text

This works if I use the statement in a cell, but **not** in the shape itself.

The idea being that if the linked cell is English, then it should show the English Text (B107) in the shape. If its not English, then it should show the Japanese text stored in (C107)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is instead of using an if statement in the shape itself, I used a cell reference in the shape object (In this example =D107).

The cell references to a helper cell (D107) which has an if statement in it.

```
=IF($C$11=$B$11,B107,C107)
```

- $C$11 is the linked cell for the combobox value
- $B$11 is the value English
- B107 is the English Text
- C107 is the Japanese Text

This means that everytime the value in C11 changes, it changes the helper cell text, which changes the text in the shapes.